# Reverberation equation

Tags: audio, noise

I am trying to understand the physical significance of \$\alpha 
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaeqySdegaaa!3796!
\$ and \$D
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamiraaaa!36C0!
\$ in the following equation:

\$y\left( n \right) = x\left( n \right) + \alpha y\left( {n - D} \right)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamyEamaabm
% aabaGaamOBaaGaayjkaiaawMcaaiabg2da9iaadIhadaqadaqaaiaa
% d6gaaiaawIcacaGLPaaacqGHRaWkcqaHXoqycaWG5bWaaeWaaeaaca
% WGUbGaeyOeI0IaamiraaGaayjkaiaawMcaaaaa!45A1!
\$

where \$x\left( n \right)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamiEamaabm
% aabaGaamOBaaGaayjkaiaawMcaaaaa!3970!
\$ is the input audio,\$y\left( n \right)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamyEamaabm
% aabaGaamOBaaGaayjkaiaawMcaaaaa!3971!
\$ is the output (echoed) audio, D is the echo delay (in samples), and \$\alpha 
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aqatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaeqySdegaaa!3796!
\$ governs the amount of echo fed back.

I have simulated above equation in MATLAB, recorded 2 sec. of audio data, quantized it and passed it to above equation and played back output signal. They clearly 'differ' to each other but I don't how to describe it. Can anyone assist on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, what you're asking is:

How do α and D affect the output sound?

You stated it in your question

> D is the echo delay (in samples) and α governs the amount of echo fed back.

This does exactly what it sounds like. If you imagine the input being "HEY!", the output would be an echo "HEY! ... hey!", with D being the amount of time between the first "HEY!" and the second "hey!" and α being the intensity of the "hey!" with respect to the "HEY!".

If this isn't what you're asking, please clarify the question.

Comment: Thanks for the response but is your rationale still valid for  `y(n)=x(n)+alpha*x(n-D)` as well? I know one is `IIR` and the other is `FIR` form but do you reckon `alpha` and `D` serve the same  purpose on both equations?

Comment: I assume it would be, I can't see any reason why not.